# Why are markers on my Google maps placed one street away from actual location

Tags: node.js, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-distancematrix-api

I am currently working on showing a set of locations on google maps, i am able to plot these markers on map, but the issue is they are misplaced by a bit, they mostly point to the nearest bus stop instead of locations.

I am using [google-distance-matrix](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-distance-matrix) npm package to get the locations.

[image: It should have pointed to Barbeque nation, instead it points to nearest bus stop]

How do i solve this?

Is this happening because google-distance-matrix has not been set to search for establishments?? if yes how do i make it search for establishments.

Comment: Sounds like traveling mode is set to "Transit", instead of "Driving".  But I don't know that package you're using

Comment: the default mode set is 'Driving' as it says here  [link](https://github.com/ecteodoro/google-distance-matrix#options)

Comment: Can you post your code so we can see what possibly could be wrong?